# Printing specified dictionaries whose specific value are equal to a separate, specified criterion

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is only pull dictionaries from the list whose date  value is within a specific month.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

listexample = []

def examplefunc():
  listexample.append(
    {'example_record':len(examplelist)+1,
     'date':datetime.strptime(input('Date (yyyy/mm/dd): ' ), '%Y/%m/%d'),
    })

examplefunc()

for i in listexample:
  print(listexample)
```

If I specified the month criterion as '3', only dictionaries with the month in the date that are equal to '3' should result/print.

If I input '2020/02/01' when input is requested, the output resolves as: `[{'example_record': 4, 'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0)}]`

The month is in the dictionary entries (as '2' in the above example), but I want to only pull those dict entries whose 'date' is == a specific month (or the current month).

I've tried iterating through the list for the specified key value within the dictionaries, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Here's an example of what I've been trying:

```
def show_all_in_current_month():
while True: 
    (examplelist[0]['date']).month == '{:%m}'.format(date.today())
    for i in range(len(examplelist)):
      print(examplelist)
    break
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: This (unbearably simple) solution worked for my issue. Thank you all for contributing.

```
for d in examplelist:
 if str(d['date'].month) == '2':
  print(d)
```

Comment: Ok, I mean, have you tried *anything at all*? Like iterating I we the list and checking for your key of interest?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried everything, including iterating through the list for the key, but nothing seems to work. Just added an example of something I tried.

Comment: `if i.month == yourDesiredMonth`?

Comment: Just a constructive criticism here - your approach looks so non-pythonic... Unless you know what you are doing 100%, don't do `while True` You will likely mess it up. Just use `for e in iterable`, that simple. Also, avoid `for i in range...`, just iterate over the elements, not indices. This is Python, utilize its incredibly simpler and intuitive syntax advantages.

Comment: All constructive criticism welcome; I'm very new to Python. I can try to remove 'while True' and 'for i in range'...I'll come back with what I find. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
listexample=[]
def examplefunc():
  listexample.append(
    {'example_record':len(listexample)+1,
     'date':datetime.strptime(input('Date (yyyy/mm/dd): ' ), '%Y/%m/%d'),
    })

#Define how many dates are you going to add 
for i in range(int(input("How many dates are you going to add?\n:"))):
   examplefunc()

def show_all_in_current_month(currentmonth):   #receives the a month and filter the dicts that are in that month
   print([dict for dict in listexample if dict['date'].month==currentmonth])
show_all_in_current_month(int(input("Which month do you want to filter the list with?\n:")))
```

Comment: Yes! this is very similar to the solution I came to (with the help of @FatihAkici) thank you so much for your help! Please see original comment for the solution that worked.

Comment: Your welcome @Steve Szuter. Yeah, I saw your solution, it works great. I've made some editions to my answer to do it more general, I'll appreciate your upvote :) . List Comprehension is one of the most commons and used methods in Python. I'm leaving you some helpful links about them, in case you want to check them out: [link 1](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension),  [link 2](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b), [link 3](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).